# Delete Javascript blobs?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

I'm having a heck of a time getting rid of these stupid things. I've got a couple of Chrome apps that deal with lots of media files; one of them I was able to use a bunch of "delete"s and a `window.URL.revokeObjectURL` that finally stopped them from building up in `chrome://blob-internals/`, but this other one, nothing seems to help. Am I missing something? I know exactly when I'm done with the damn thing, but there seems to be nothing I can do.

Specifically, I'm using a File object in a block like this:

```
ref.file(function(f) {
    // Do some stuff...
    // and now I'm done!
    delete f
});
```

Here's the actual source of my app:

https://github.com/pkulak/photo-importer

and here's the one where I think I actually solved the problem, but who really knows:

https://github.com/pkulak/drive-slideshow

Comment: http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This looks like you have a memory leak.

*JavaScript* doesn't have a "delete" in the sense you're talking about, it garbage collects as properties and variables become orphaned. The [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator is one such way to achieve that - it removes the definition of a property from an *Object*.
Using `delete` correctly means using it on a property, not a `var`iable. The reason it works on some variables is because of what happens with `var` in the global namespace (i.e. they become properties of `window`). This also means you can't `delete` a parameter.

Further, note that once a function has finished invoking, if there are no references being kept alive then all of it's internals will be GC'd.

Next, consider

```
var o = {};
o.a = [];
o.b = o.a;
delete o.a;
```

What is `o.b` now?

```
`o.b; // []`
```

It's still pointing at the *Array* even though we deleted the `o.a` reference. This means that the *Array* **won't** be garbage collected.

So what does this mean for you?

To get rid of your *Blobs*, you need to destroy all the references to them.

Yes, revoking the *URI* is part of it, but you also need to remove references all the way through your code. If you're finding this difficult, I'd suggest you wrap all your *Blobs* so you can at least minimise the problem.

```
var myBlob = (function () {
    var key, o;
    function myBlob(blob) {
        var url;
        this.blob = blob;
        blob = null;
        this.getURL = function () {
            if (url) return url;
            return url = URL.createObjectURL(this.blob);
        };
        this.dispose = function () {
            if (url) url = URL.revokeObjectURL(url), undefined;
            this.blob = null;
        };
    }
    o = new Blob();
    for (key in o)
        (function (key) {
            Object.defineProperty(myBlob.prototype, key, {
                enumerable: true,
                configurable: true,
                get: function () {return this.blob[key];}
            });
        }(key));
    o = key = undefined;
    return myBlob;
}());
```

Now, instead of your regular *Blob* creation use `new myBlob(blob)` **immediately as you make your blob**, keeping no other references to the blob. Then when you're finished with your *Blob*, call `myWrappedBlob.dispose();` and it should free it up to be GC'd. If it's *really* necessary to pass the *Blob* into something directly, I gave it the property `myBlob.blob`.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right. I keep a list of file references, and it may be that each blob I create using a reference is still being held there. I'll try getting rid of those items as soon as I'm done with them.

Comment: Just as a follow up, it looks like there was never a leak in the app, even though blob-internals was filling up. I guess Chrome doesn't remove references to file-system blobs, but they don't actually contribute to the working memory since they are, apparently, not in memory to begin with.

Comment: @PhilKulak Where did you read that the blobs are not in memory? I am dealing with similar problems.

Comment: @PabloJomer, no idea, sorry. It's been so long at this point, I remember almost nothing about this project. :D