# Delete specific blob data or clear out all stored blob data entirely with JS

Tags: javascript, blob

In my app there is the ability to generate PDFs. The library I am using doesn't dispose of them after they are created and download. Eventually, after generating enough PDFs, the stored blob data becomes so large that it crashes the browser.

One solution would be to refresh the browser after print. That would really screw up the user experience though because they would lose their current print parameters.

The solution to that would be to store the print parameters in `sessionStorage` or something so that they are restored when a refresh is done.

At any rate, the easiest solution to implement would be just to clear out the specific blob data, or clear all blob data, once the print is done.

This is what I am seeing chrome://blob-internals. The first item is what I want to delete; the two items below the line are just URL references to the blob.

**How do I clear this out either specifically or just clearing out all blobs in Javascipt?**

[image]

Tried to do the following:

```
handleDownload(filename, blob, url, e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    saveAs(blob, filename);
    this.props.pdfPrint(false);
    delete blob;
}
```

But this gives a `Deleting local variable in strict mode` error. Tried to:

```
handleDownload(filename, blob, url, e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    saveAs(blob, filename);
    this.props.pdfPrint(false);
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    var test = {};
    test = blob
    delete test.blob;
}
```

Which just deletes one of the references to the blob, but not the blob it self.

In reading this, all references need to be removed first:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22899690/3123109